# C++ calling user defined function

Tags: compiler-construction

I want to achieve the following:

User can define some high level function in some language, for example:

assume `foo()` and `bar()` return boolean values

```
boolean oneUserDefinedFunction
  result = foo() logicalAND bar();
  return result
```

And there is a static mapping which maps from `foo` to a native C++ function `foo_cpp`, and from `bar` to c++ native `bar_cpp`.
And in C++ code, and it is executed as:

```
bool oneUserDefinedFunction() {
  bool result = foo_cpp() && bar_cpp();
  return result;
}
```

The point of this idea is, users have the flexibility to define arbitrary simple logic which can contain variable number of predefined function calls and combination of different logical operations (logicalAND and logicalOR, and logicNOT, etc) on top of the function returns to compute a final result.

But I am not quite sure how to implement this.
Some suggestion I got is to use lua to define the user function. I did some quick search and it seems workable to call lua from C++. But in my case, I need `c++ calls lua function, which calls c++ function (the implementation of foo is native foo_cpp")`. Not very sure if it is possible with c++ and lua interaction.

I really need some idea/suggestion here. If lua is not possible, what else options do I have?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You could simply compare the name of the user function unknown by the interpreter (you quote `foo`/`bar`), and check if it matches with native hard defined functions in your program. If it does, these functions modify the stack or anything else you use to circulate your data to give the expected result, if not, then you're dealing with the "error"?

Comment: However, I think a better way to think about it is to define a [FFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface).